# Create Dataframe for What-If Visualization by Resorting Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create an experimental dataframe (that will be used only for the comparative viz) from other correlated dataframes and then sort the column values independent of each other to later visualize and show what correlated data should look like (because my current data actually shows no correlation)

```
experimental_df = full_df[['Token_Rarity','Price_USD']]
```

Becomes:

```
experimental_df.sort_values(by=['Token_Rarity','Price_USD'],ascending=[True,True])
```

I'm trying to get the lowest value in Token Column, and lowest value in price column, or vise versa, regardless of any other values or arguments. Current result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
experimental_df = pd.DataFrame()
experimental_df['Token_Rarity'] = full_df['Token_Rarity'].sort_values()
experimental_df['Price_USD'] = full_df['Price_USD'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```